How to parallelly execute "delete" query maintaining trainsactionality in JPA, Spring Boot
Consider this code:
`
@Transactional
    public ServiceResponse<Void> deleteFlowPlan(Context context)
    {
        ServiceRequest<Map<String, Object>> serviceRequest = context.get(BaseKeys.DELETE_FLOW);
        Map<String,Object> request = serviceRequest.getPayload();
        Long flowPlanId= (Long) request.get("flowPlanId");

    if(Objects.isNull(flowPlanId))
        throw new AllocationRuntimeException(ErrorCodes.INVALID_INPUT.getError("Flowplanid can not be null."));

    FlowPlanDetails flowPlanDetails = flowPlanDetailsRepository.findByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId);
    if(Objects.isNull(flowPlanDetails))
        throw new AllocationRuntimeException(ErrorCodes.INVALID_INPUT.getError("Flowplanid could not be found."));

    wavemakerFlowPlanRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId);
    wavemakerIdcCalculationsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId);
    flowPlanDetailsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId);

    return ServiceResponseBuilder.get(null);

}`

Now as you can see Im making three IO calls here:
       wavemakerFlowPlanRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId); wavemakerIdcCalculationsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId); flowPlanDetailsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId);
I want to make them called parallely and if anyone of them fails the entire transaction should rollback.
I tried this but it doesn't gaurantee the transactionality. If there is anyway possible please share your insights:
Tried this:
`CompletableFuture wavemakerFlowPlanFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> wavemakerFlowPlanRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId));
CompletableFuture wavemakerIdcCalculationsFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> wavemakerIdcCalculationsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId));
CompletableFuture flowPlanDetailsFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> flowPlanDetailsRepository.deleteByFlowPlanId(flowPlanId));
CompletableFuture.allOf(wavemakerFlowPlanFuture, wavemakerIdcCalculationsFuture, flowPlanDetailsFuture).get();`

But this is throwing this exception:

java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@66c49abb[Completed exceptionally: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call]


All the delete statements will mark the associated row for deletion (REMOVED entity state) however it will not be deleted as long as you/EntityManager/Session issues a flush() call to the DB to commit the changes. So if any deletes fail the Persistence Context will rollback all the changes. The top-level Transactional annotation proxies the complete method and if you invoke repository methods in parallel then each would have to have its own Transaction boundaries (via Propagation)
